# Email body variable

Tags: javascript, cordova, email

```
<label for="ctbq">Toner B431:</label>
<select name="ctbq">
   <option value="00" >00</option>
   <option value="01">01</option>
   <option value="02">02</option>
   <option value="03">03</option>
   <option value="04">04</option>
   <option value="05">05</option>
   <option value="06">06</option>
   <option value="07">07</option>
   <option value="08">08</option>
   <option value="09">09</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
</select>  

<script>
function email(){      
  var a = document.getElementsByName('ctbq')
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    var e = a[i];
    cordova.plugins.email.open({
      to:      'teste@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Greetings',
      body:    'Hello How are you?' +e.value,
    });
  }
}
</script>

<button onclick="pegaValor();email()">Email</button>
```

---

I wanted to load the value of the `ctbq` label into the body of the email. I am trying more as I am not very experienced in the subject of programming JavaScript. If someone can help me, thank you.

Comment: I believe www.stackoverflow.com is english only

Comment: Your code should work. Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: See my edited answer pretty sure you have a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

There looks like a misplaced comma at the end of your options;

```
 body: 'Hello How are you?' + e.value,
```

Should be:

```
body: 'Hello How are you?' + e.value
```

I assume because you are using a loop you have more than 1 element with the name="ctbq" or using a form? If not then you could give the select element an id and omit the for loop.

```
function email(){      
    var a = document.getElementById('YOUR_ID');
    var selectedValue = a.value;
    cordova.plugins.email.open({
         to:      'teste@gmail.com',
         subject: 'Greetings',
          body:    'Hello How are you?' + selectedValue
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="YOUR_ID">Toner B431:</label>
<select name="ctbq" Id="YOUR_ID">
        <option value="00" >00</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

The label for attribute needs to be the same as the id of the element you want to attach it to.

Comment: "Try this" is not a useful explanation of your solution.

Comment: The value of  a `<select>` is the same as the value of the selected option.

Comment: Edited to add more info and comments on the lines of code that get the value or text. Also pointed out that you could omit the for loop if you use an id.

Comment: I also added how to get the text of the selected option.

Comment: Since the text is the same as the value, there's not much point in that.

Comment: There's no good reason to use `a[i].options[a[i].selectedIndex].value` instead of `a[i].value`.

Comment: Agreed. I think the real problem with the Op's code is the misplaced comma.

Comment: @Barmar do you suggest I remove the extra bits in my answer as I am pretty confident the error was a syntax error in the ops options for the email?. I am still learning myself.

Comment: Argh making a right idiot of myself here!!! Thanks. Learned something new today. a[i].value is a lot more concise.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the comma at the end of his email options object? Same place I had my syntax error.